# fazer o ScrollView rolar para baixo automaticamente

Tags: android, android-layout

olá, tenho uma aplicação de bate papo porém conforme vai acomulando mensagens o usuario é obrigado a ver tds mensagens digitadas desde a primeira, ele deve rola a barra até o final para ver a ultima mensagem, ja pesquisei algumas formas de resolver isso mas não encontrei. a solução que achei foi essa:

```
      scrollViewObject.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            scroll.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
        }
    }, 600);
```

porém da erro. alguem consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Coloque na pergunta o erro dá.

Comment: ele não reconhece a parte 
     scrollViewObject.postDelayed
e 
     scroll.fullScroll

Comment: ele não reconhece a parte 
     scrollViewObject.postDelayed
e 
     scroll.fullScroll